# How to get the hidden type of boost::variant variable while debugging in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, boost, visual-studio-debugging

I have a variable `m_Value`:

```
boost::variant< int64_t, float64_t, std::string > m_Value
```

I want to get the hidden type while I debug: is it int64_t OR float64_t OR std::string?

Unfortunately I cannot find it in the variable's description in "Locals" Window in Visual Studio (see below). Do you know where it ist displayed?

[image]

Comment: The `which_` member tells you (by index) - `0` is the first type, `1` the second, and so on. It may be possible to write a .natvis visualizer that displays the type somehow, but I'm not sure if those are even available in VS2010.

Comment: Prove member `which_` is already very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are debug visualizers here:  https://github.com/KindDragon/CPPDebuggerVisualizers, it includes support for boost types:

- `boost::shared_ptr`, `boost::weak_ptr`, `boost::intrusive_ptr`,
- `boost::shared_array`, `boost::scoped_ptr`, `boost::scoped_array`
- `boost::ptr_array`, `boost::ptr_vector`, `boost::ptr_list`,
- `boost::ptr_deque`, `boost::ptr_map`, `boost::ptr_set`,
- `boost::ptr_multimap`, `boost::ptr_multiset` `boost::array`,
- `boost::dynamic_bitset`, `boost::circular_buffer` `boost::unordered_map`,
- `boost::unordered_set`, `boost::unordered_multimap`,
- `boost::unordered_multiset`, `boost::intrusive::list`,
- `boost::intrusive::slist`, `boost::intrusive::set`
- `boost::container::basic_string`, `boost::container::deque`,
- `boost::container::vector` `boost::optional`, `boost::any`, `boost::variant`
- `boost::filesystem::path`, `boost::filesystem::directory_entry`,
- `boost::filesystem::file_status` `boost::posix_time::ptime`,
- `boost::posix_time::time_duration` `boost::multiprecision`
- `boost::rational` `boost::regex` `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr`
- `boost::tribool` `boost::unique_lock` `boost::uuids::uuid`

Comment: Unfortunately the DebuggerVisualizers seem to be available from VS 2012 onwards.

Comment: Similar things existed but using a different definition format. A Google search should help. I seem to remember `autoexec.exp` or similar filename

Comment: Yes, [this link](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers) shows how to do this in section **Native C++ Debugger Visualizers for MSVS 2005 / 2008 / 2010 ¶**.